# How can I write dynamic if condition without using eval?

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement, dynamic, eval

I'm trying to write a condition that accumulates filters at run-time and builds a conditional statement that looks something like:

location == "mumbai" || location == "tokyo" && type == "car" || ....

which can then be inserted into an if statement.

There are plenty of questions for similar or identical requests on StackOverflow and other forums, but best I can tell they all seem to use JavaScript's eval() method which is :

- A: Not considered safe
- B: the code you have to write to facilitate eval() is messy and undesirable.

Is there a way to do this without eval()?

Edit 1:

(For clarity)
There are multiple types of filter (as in the example above we see location and type) so in a high level example the condition's structure would look like:

if the location is this, this or this, and the type is this or this and...

so it will evaluate to true if the location is ANY of the locations filtered AND if those results are of ANY of the types filtered.

So if I'm filtering by mumbai and tokyo for cars, the results will only return true for Cars in Tokyo or Cars in Mumbai, but false for tractors in Mumbai or Aeroplanes in Tokyo, as well as Cars in Moscow or Cars in London

Comment: do you have some more examples? which parts are dynamic?

Comment: Hard to say exactly without seeing what you have but usually you collect predicates and run though them.

Comment: @NinaScholz the entire if condition would be dynamic! So I want to build a statement depending on which filters the user has selected. The code I currently have wouldn't apply to this approach as I was trying to filter each time a checkbox was checked using a for loop. This dynamic solution is something I considered and gave 3 days research to before considering other possibilities to avoid eval(). I can provide my existing code but I'm not sure it would help. Would building a regex be a better solution than a string to be evaluated?

Comment: I've seen arrays of objects used in some projects, something like `[{ operator: 'or', field: 'location', condition '==', value: 'mumbai' }]`. You can treat them in code without `eval`

Comment: @assoron does this function not carry the same dangers as eval? It evaluates a manipulable string and executes it, no?

Comment: have you tried building an array with your filters and checking if the current item is in said array?

Comment: @assoron the only difference using `Function` is that it won't be able to access local variables from where it's called, but it's as unsafe, you can still manipulate the DOM, do ajax calls or anything else that can be a major security issue

Comment: @SLowLoris That's actually the current system, but the issue is it only works if the user only enters one filter of each category, because it's looking for say, results in Mumbai that are in Tokyo, which obviously returns no results. That was my thinking for an alternative when I initially researched this.

Comment: I have added a clarification edit, can those who put the question on hold please tell me if anything else is needed?